# Python tkinter image, function not working

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, image-manipulation

```
import pyautogui
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageTk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('capture')
canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 400, height = 100)
canvas1.pack()

on = tk.PhotoImage(file = 'D:/on.png')
off = tk.PhotoImage(file = 'D:/off.png')

def myScreenshot(event):
    myScreenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
    myScreenshot.save('C:/Users/*Username/Desktop/capture.jpg')

def capture():
    if onButton['image'] == on:
        onButton['image'] = on
        root.bind('<Shift-Z>', myScreenshot)

    else:
        root.unbind('<Shift-Z>')
        onButton['image'] = off
        

onButton = tk.Button(image = on, command=capture)
canvas1.create_window(200, 50, window=onButton)

root.mainloop()
```

so I have 2 questions;

1. What I intended is after I press 'on' button, whenever I press Shift + Z, it will capture my whole screen. However it is not working for some reason. There is no error.
2. I want to let 'on' button return when I click 'off' button. But it is not working. Only works 'on' to 'off'

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code snippet that works.

I couldn't get it to work using the image on the button as a flag, although if you wrap `off` in a `str` then it might work.

By using a boolean to test the status the button change works.

You had the button turned **on** to begin with so the `<Key-Z>` binding could not be made.

```py
def capture():
    global flag
    if flag:
        onButton.config( image = on, text = "on")
        flag = False
        root.bind('<Key-Z>', myScreenshot)
    else:
        onButton.config( image = off, text = "off")
        flag = True
        root.unbind('<Key-Z>')

flag = True
onButton = tk.Button(image = off, text = "off", compound = "top", command=capture)
canvas1.create_window(200, 50, window=onButton)
```

There is an alternative to testing image, test the text.

```py
def capture():
    if onButton['text'] == 'off':
        onButton.config( image = on, text = "on")
        root.bind('<Key-Z>', myScreenshot)
    else:
        onButton.config( image = off, text = "off")
        root.unbind('<Key-Z>')
onButton = tk.Button(image = off, text = "off", compound = "top", command=capture)
canvas1.create_window(200, 50, window=onButton)
```

Comment: Thans! It is working , however, is there any way to not adding text? I don't need any text around my button.

Comment: Try this `if onButton['image'] == str(off)`.